# Is this short sentence correctly punctuated?

Tags: punctuation

Take a look at the above-mentioned sentence.

**We buy more, possess more but forget our responsibility towards the society**

Is this correctly punctuated?

Comment: I think "and" would be the right choice. **We buy more and possess more**

Answer (score 1):

Punctuation is used sometimes for a grammatical purpose: different punctuation would change the meaning of what is being said.

In this case, however, punctuation is indicating how the sentence might be spoken, with the commas showing where the speaker would pause. On that basis, a comma after "...possess more" would be a good idea to separate the thought about possessing  from the thought about forgetting. Without the comma the reader might be confused for a moment that buying was somehow being contrasted with "possessing and forgetting".

Comment: Agreed. There is also a full-stop missing from the end of the sentence and that isn't optional